# Android OpenGL ES2 triangles rendered with opacity

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am loading models from server as JSON format which I created in Three.js BufferGeometry and stored position and uv attributes in a JSON file, when I load to openGL ES2 everything is nice but some faces do not appear until I rotate the view if it has a texture or appear semi transparent if it has a color.
the vertices values and order generated from Three.js without any changes so I assume there are in the right order so it should be no reversed faces.
[image]

[image]
this is the fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main() {
    vec4 tex=texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
    gl_FragColor=v_Color+tex;
}
```

and the rendering code:

```
    private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
// private static final int BYTES_PER_SHORT = 2;
private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 4;
private static final int UV_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
private static final int ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT = POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT + UV_COMPONENT_COUNT;
private static final int STRIDE = ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

private VertexArray vertexArray;

private float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] modelViewProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

TextureShaderProgram shaderProgram;
int textureid;
// ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

public Geometry(Context context, JSONObject element) throws JSONException {     
    /*
     * JSONArray indecies = element.getJSONArray("indexes"); short[] indexes
     * = new short[indecies.length()]; for (int y = 0; y <
     * indecies.length(); y++) { indexes[y] = (short) indecies.getInt(y); }
     */
    // indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indexes.length *
    // BYTES_PER_SHORT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
    // indexBuffer.put(indexes).position(0);
    JSONArray vertices = element.getJSONArray("vertices");
    JSONArray uvs = element.getJSONArray("uvs");
    JSONArray matrix = element.getJSONArray("matrix");
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.length(); y++) {
        modelMatrix[y] = (float) matrix.getDouble(y);
    }
    JSONObject material = element.getJSONObject("material");
    int color = Color.parseColor(material.getString("color"));
    String bmpString = material.getString("map");
    int n = vertices.length() / 3;
    float[] data;
    data = new float[n * STRIDE];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT] = (float) vertices.getDouble(i * 3);
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 1] = (float) vertices.getDouble(i * 3 + 1);
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 2] = (float) vertices.getDouble(i * 3 + 2);
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 3] = Color.red(color) / 255f;
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 4] = Color.green(color) / 255f;
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 5] = Color.blue(color) / 255f;
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 6] = Color.alpha(color) / 255f;
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 7] = bmpString.equals("") ? 0f : (float) uvs.getDouble(k);
        data[i * ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT + 8] = bmpString.equals("") ? 0f : (float) uvs.getDouble(k + 1);
        k += 2;
    }
    vertexArray = new VertexArray(data);

    shaderProgram = new TextureShaderProgram(context, R.raw.texture_vertex_shader, R.raw.texture_fragment_shader);
    textureid = bmpString.equals("") ? 0 : TextureHelper.loadTexture(TextureHelper.decodeBase64(bmpString));
}

private void bindData(TextureShaderProgram shaderProgram) {
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0, shaderProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(), POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, shaderProgram.getColorAttributeLocation(), COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, shaderProgram.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(), UV_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
}

public void draw(float[] projectionMatrix) {
    multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    shaderProgram.useProgram();
    shaderProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, textureid);
    bindData(shaderProgram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexArray.getCapacity() / ALL_COMPONENT_COUNT);
    // glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer.capacity(),
    // GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
}
```

the vertexData class:

```
    private final FloatBuffer floatBuffer;
private final int capacity;

public VertexArray(float[] vertexData) {
    floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertexData);
    capacity = floatBuffer.capacity();
}

public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset, int attributeLocation, int componentCount, int stride) {
    floatBuffer.position(dataOffset);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
    floatBuffer.position(0);
}

public final int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}
```

Comment: Did your request a depth buffer? And enable depth testing?

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Depth function is not set, so OpenGL ES is drawing in the order of triangles based on the indices data. You have to enable depth test which will sort the triangles based on the depth information from the camera.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```